# Is it possible in Unity Mirror to connect and sync not spawned objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-mirror

I have an object what I use only in one scene, so I do not want to make it prefab. This object has network identity, and a script which is increasing a syncvar integer in the update method. When the game starts this object got disable because the server is not running. When I start hosting the server this object got enabled. Everything fine is this point but when a client is joining this object is still disabled in the client and not synchronized.

If I am right it is because the objects are not connected to each other. how and I solve it without making this object a prefab and just spawn it?

How can I spawn objects without a player prefab with authority on the server (it would be a singleton service object)?

Answer (score 3):

NetworkIdentities have to be spawned.
If it is already in your scene you can enforce it to be spawned by using

```
NetworkServer.SpawnObjects();
```

[NetworkServer.SpawnObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkServer.SpawnObjects.html)

Also you can spawn any prefab you defined in the NetworkManager. Look for the Registered Spawnable Prefabs Array.
To spawn a registered prefab you can use

```
NetworkServer.Spawn();
```

[NetworkServer.Spawn](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkServer.Spawn.html)

For example spawn a registered prefab on the server using a Command:

```
[Command]
public void CmdSpawnGameObject()
{      
   var spawnObject = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
   NetworkServer.Spawn(spawnObject, connectionToClient);  
}
```

> How can I spawn objects without a player prefab with authority on the
> server (it would be a singleton service object)?

You can't. You have to have a playerPrefab spawned and you have to have authority. But you can also hand over authority using

```
identity.AssignClientAuthority(conn);
```

[Authority with Mirror](https://mirror-networking.com/docs/Articles/Guides/Authority.html?q=give%20authority)